# Can I insert a table name by using a query parameter?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have an SQL Alchemy engine where I try to insert parameters via sqlalchemy.sql.text to protect against SQL injection.

The following code works, where I code variables for the condition and conditions values.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.sql import text

db_engine = create_engine(...)

db_engine.execute(
         text(
             'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE :condition_1 = :condition_1_value'), condition_1="name", condition_1_value="John"
         )
).fetchall()
```

However, when I try to code the variable name for `table_name`, it returns an error.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.sql import text

db_engine = create_engine(...)

db_engine.execute(
         text(
             'SELECT * FROM :table_name WHERE :condition_1 = :condition_1_value'), table_name="table_1", condition_1="name", condition_1_value="John"
         )
).fetchall()
```

Any ideas why this does not work?

EDIT:
I know that it has something to do with the `table_name` not being a string, but I am not sure how to do it in another way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Any ideas why this does not work?

Query parameters are used to supply the *values* of things (usually column values), not the *names* of things (tables, columns, etc.). Every database I've seen works that way.

So, despite the ubiquitous advice that dynamic SQL is a "Bad Thing", there are certain cases where it is simply necessary. This is one of them.

```py
table_name = "table_1"  # NOTE: Do not use untrusted input here!
stmt = text(f'SELECT * FROM "{table_name}" …')
```

Also, check the results you get from trying to parameterize a column name. You may not be getting what you expect.

```py
stmt = text("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE :condition_1 = :condition_1_value")
db_engine.execute(stmt, dict(condition_1="name", condition_1_value="John"))
```

will not produce the equivalent of

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE name = 'John'
```

It will render the equivalent of

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE 'name' = 'John'
```

and will not throw an error, but it will also return no rows because `'name' = 'John'` will never be true.